# Growatt Web Data using requests and beautiful soup with login

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to login into server.growatt.com to extract my solar and battery data as I want to automate the upload to pvoutput.org.
I only need to pick up a few data points once logged on. I try to search for the word 'Solar' using beautiful soup find function after using html parser. See code. It returns None when run. I print the entire html output but Solar is not found. If I inspect the html on the web site Solar is listed. I have added asyncio.sleep to give the web site time to log in. I believe the login is working as the returned file is large but the embedded data is not there. Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

```
import requests
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from config import username, password, lang

URL = 'https://server.growatt.com/index'
LOGIN = 'https://server.growatt.com/login'

s = requests.session()

login_payload = {
    'account': username,
    'password': password,
    'lang' : lang
    }

login_req = s.post(LOGIN, data=login_payload)
print(login_req.status_code)

async def main():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
asyncio.run(main())

soup = bs(s.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')
find = soup.find('Solar')
print(soup)
print(find)
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are trying to make your code Asynchronous while it's not at all.

Firstly, you've to use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/v0.8.3/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests) async method.

Secondly, the login process require two `POST` requests for two different `urls`.

Below, I've used a high level `Async` library called [trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

On the other-side, I've used [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) which support async requests.

Below is a simple code for it:

```
import trio
import httpx


async def main():
    headers = {
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None, headers=headers) as client:
        data1 = {
            "userName": "testusername",
            "password": "testpass",
        }
        r1 = await client.post('https://oss.growatt.com/login', data=data1)
        print(r1.json())

        data2 = {
            "account": "testusername",
            "password": "testpass",
            "validateCode": ""
        }

        r2 = await client.post('https://server.growatt.com/login', data=data2)
        print(r2.json())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
{'result': 0, 'msg': 'Wrong user name or password'}
{'result': -2, 'msg': 'Username Password Error'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used the code with data2 account and password details correct and the return code is {'result': 1} which I guess means it logs in. What I am still unable to get is any data once logged in.

Comment: I’ve no valid login in order to check that for you as I believe you need to track the requests to complete the login process or call the direct internal link directly